# Update events in Fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to update events in Fullcalendar. I'm able to print events with an ajax call but then I don't know how to make those events editable. I've been lookig for internet and this is what I've tried, but it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.get('/controls/calendar', function (data) {
        drawControl(data);
    });


// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

function allControls(controls) {
    var arrayControls=[];
    for (i in controls) {
        var level= controls[i].level
        var day= controls[i].day
        var period=controls[i].period
        console.log(controls[i].period)
        arrayControls.push({title:level, start:day, description:"period", textColor: 'black'})
    }
        return arrayControls;
}



function drawControl(controls) {
        console.log(controls[0])

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            aspectRatio: 1,
            contentHeight: 500,
            scrollTime: '24:00:00',
            minTime: '07:00:00',
            maxTime: '24:00:00',
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header:{left:"prev,next,today",
            center:"title",
            right:"month, agendaWeek, agendaDay"},



            events: allControls(controls),

            eventRender: function(event, element) {

                var bloodLevel=event.title

                if(bloodLevel >= 180) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'red');
                }
                else if(bloodLevel < 70) {
                    element.css('background-color', 'yellow');
                }
            },
            eventClick: function(event, element) {

            event.title = "CLICKED!";

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

}
            //
    // put your options and callbacks here
})

}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in fullcalendar.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable : true,
});
```

You can also do this event specific:

```
var event = {editable:true, start : moment(), end:moment()};
```